# Constrained linear regression coefficients in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, lm

I'm estimating several ordinary least squares linear regressions in R. I want to constrain the estimated coefficients across the regressions such that they're the same. For example, I have the following:

```
z1 ~ x + y
z2 ~ x + y
```

And I would like the estimated coefficient on y in the first regression to be equal to the estimated coefficient on x in the second.

Is there a straight-forward way to do this? Thanks in advance.

**More detailed edit**

I'm trying to estimate a system of linear demand functions, where the corresponding welfare function is quadratic. The welfare function has the form:

```
W = 0.5*ax*(Qx^2) + 0.5*ay*(Qy^2) + 0.5*bxy*Qx*Qy + 0.5*byx*Qy*Qx + cx*Qx + cy*Qy
```

Therefore, it follows that the demand functions are:

```
dW/dQx = Px = 2*0.5*ax*Qx + 0 + 0.5*bxy*Qy + 0.5*byx*Qy + 0 + cx
dW/dQx = Px = ax*Qx + 0.5*(bxy + byx)*Qy + cx
```

and

```
dW/dQy = Py = ay*Qy + 0.5*(byx + bxy)*Qx + cy
```

I would like to constrain the system so that byx = bxy (the cross-product coefficients in the welfare function). If this condition holds, the two demand functions become:

```
Px = ax*Qx + bxy*Qy + cy
Py = ay*Qy + bxy*Qy + cy
```

I have price (`Px` and `Py`) and quantity (`Qx` and `Qy`) data, but what I'm really interested in is the welfare (`W`) which I have no data for.

I know how to calculate and code all the matrix formulae for constrained least squares (which would take a fair few lines of code to get the coefficients, standard errors, measures of fit etc that come standard with `lm()`). But I was hoping there might be an existing R function (i.e. something that can be done to the `lm()` function) so that I wouldn't have to code all of this.

Comment: Well, you could take the sum of squares (as the sum of the sum of squares of both models) and minimize it. Since you have 5 parameters it might be a bit lengthy to solve that by hand, but a CAS might help with that. Or you use a numeric solver.

Comment: Maybe package `quadprog` might be able to do this.

Comment: This problem interests me, but I am not sure how to approach it.  If you ask the same question on the statistics sister site, Cross Validated, and you get I nice answer maybe I can write the code.  Alternatively, maybe I can offer a bounty in the future or just find the time to work it out.  Maybe Bayesian could do it easier than frequentist.

Comment: Thanks Mark... I was hoping I wouldn't have to code all the matrix operatoins myself, but if push comes to shove, that may well be what I have to do.

Answer (score 2):

For your specified regression:

```
Px = ax*Qx + bxy*Qy + cy
Py = ay*Qy + bxy*Qy + cy
```

We can introduce a grouping factor:

```
id <- factor(rep.int(c("Px", "Py"), c(length(Px), length(Py))),
             levels = c("Px", "Py"))
```

We also need to combine data:

```
z <- c(Px, Py)    ## response
x <- c(Qx, Qy)    ## covariate 1
y <- c(Qy, Qy)    ## covariate 2
```

Then we can fit a linear model using `lm` with a formula:

```
z ~ x + y + x:id
```

Answer (score 0):

If the x and y values are the same, then you could use this model:

```
lm( I(z1+z2)~ x +y )  # Need to divide coefficients by 2
```

If they are separate data then you could rbind the two datasets after renaming z2 to z1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't want the coefficient to be the same on the same variable... I want the coefficients to be fixed on the cross-product terms (the non-principle diagonal elements if I were to create a matrix of estimated coefficients across all of my models).

Comment: Your models do not appear to have any cross products, so it appears you are expecting an answer to a question that is not yet posed in theory or, as is expected at SO, with an example.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear on my part. I replied off-hand without reflecting on what I was writing, the assumed knowledge that goes with it. I'll put a more detailed example in my question to make it clearer.